# Flutter || Send Apk and Ipa to multiple email using Codemagic

Tags: flutter, continuous-integration, continuous-delivery, codemagic

I'm working on a flutter project and I built an Apk and iOS using Codemagic, the build succeeded and it was sent to my email address. Is there a way to send it to another email like change my email in configuration with another email. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, you can change or add more recipients in `App Settings` > `Notifications` > `Email` if you build with Workflow Editor.

or in `codemagic.yaml` file

```
publishing:
  email:
    recipients:
      - name1@example.com
      - name2@example.com
```